# How to getSelectors through passing arg in endpoint.select() in Redux RTK

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I currently have this piece of code.

```
const initialState = documentsAdapter.getInitialState()
export const setupsApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    tagTypes: ['Setup'],
    endpoints: builder => ({
        getSetups: builder.query({
            query: (documentId) => ({
                url: `/documents/${documentId}/setups`,
                method: 'GET'
            }),
            providesTags: ['Setup']
        }),
       
    })
})


export const {
    useGetSetupsQuery,
    useAddSetupsMutation,
    useUpdateSetupsMutation,
    useDeleteSetupsMutation
} = apiSlice
```

And now I want to make use of the of the getSelector and do something like this (not implemented).

```
export const selectSetupsResult = setupsApiSlice.endpoints.getSetups.select()

// Creates memoized selector
const selectSetupsData = createSelector(
    selectSetupsResult,
    setupsResult => setupsResult.data // normalized state object with ids & entities
)

export const {
    selectAll: selectAllSetups,
    selectById: selectSetupById,
    selectIds: selectSetupIds,
} = setupsAdapter.getSelectors(state => selectSetupsData(state) ?? initialState)
```

The problem that I encounter is that endpoint.select() needs an argument in my case so that I can call setups on the correct documentId. I know I could just call all the setups and then filter out the ones that have the same documentId, but I was wondering if there is any other way. Even if it means not calling the endpoints.select() and still being able to use the getSelectors().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const initialState = documentsAdapter.getInitialState()
export const setupsApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    tagTypes: ['Setup'],
    endpoints: builder => ({
        getSetups: builder.query({
            query: (documentId) => ({
                url: `/documents/${documentId}/setups`,
                method: 'GET'
            }),
            // Add transformResponse
            transformResponse: (responseData) => {
                return documentsAdapter.setAll(initialState, responseData)
            },
            providesTags: ['Setup']
        }),
       
    })
})


// Define function to get selectors based on arguments (query) of getSetups
export const getSelectors = (
  query,
) => {
  const selectSetupsResult = setupsApiSlice.endpoints.getSetups.select(query)

  const adapterSelectors = createSelector(
    selectSetupsResult,
    (result) => documentsAdapter.getSelectors(() => result?.data ?? initialState)
  )

  return {
    selectAll: createSelector(adapterSelectors, (s) =>
      s.selectAll(undefined)
    ),
    selectEntities: createSelector(adapterSelectors, (s) =>
      s.selectEntities(undefined)
    ),
    selectIds: createSelector(adapterSelectors, (s) =>
      s.selectIds(undefined)
    ),
    selectTotal: createSelector(adapterSelectors, (s) =>
      s.selectTotal(undefined)
    ),
    selectById: (id) => createSelector(adapterSelectors, (s) =>
      s.selectById(s, id)
    ),
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in a component as:

```js
  const { isFetching } = useGetSetupsQuery({id: 1})

  // Dinamically get selectors based on parent query
  const { selectAll: selectAllFromId1, selectById: selectByIdFromId1 } = getSelectors({id: 1})

  // Use selectors based on parent id 1
  const allFromId1 = useSelector(selectAllFromId1)
  const setup1fromId1 = useSelector(selectByIdFromId1(5)) // get id 5
```